# Is TensorRT "floating-point 16" precision mode non-deterministic on Jetson TX2?

Tags: deterministic, non-deterministic, tensorrt, nvidia-jetson, half-precision-float

I'm using TensorRT **FP16 precision mode** to optimize my deep learning model. And I use this optimised model on **Jetson TX2**. While testing the model, I have observed that TensorRT inference engine is **not deterministic**. In other words, my optimized model gives  different FPS values  between 40 and 120 FPS for same input images.

I started to think that the source of the non-determinism is floating point operations when I see [this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/782499/cuda-programming-and-performance/cuda-result-changes-time-to-time/post/4338626/#4338626) comment about CUDA:

> "If your code uses floating-point atomics, results may differ from run
>   to run because floating-point operations are generally not
>   associative, and the order in which data enters a computation (e.g. a
>   sum) is non-deterministic when atomics are used."

Is type of precision such as FP16, FP32 and INT8 affects determinism of TensorRT? Or anything?

Do you have any thoughs?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the function clock() that I used for measuring latencies. The clock() function was measuring the CPU time latency, but what I want to do is to measure real time latency. Now I am using std::chrono to measure the latencies. Now inference results are latency-deterministic.

That was wrong one, ([clock()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/))

```
int main ()
{
  clock_t t;
  int f;
  t = clock();
  inferenceEngine(); // Tahmin yapılıyor
  t = clock() - t;
  printf ("It took me %d clicks (%f seconds).\n",t,((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  return 0;
}
```

Use Cuda Events like this, ([CudaEvent](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/how-implement-performance-metrics-cuda-cc/))

```
cudaEvent_t start, stop;
cudaEventCreate(&start);
cudaEventCreate(&stop);

cudaEventRecord(start);
inferenceEngine(); // Do the inference

cudaEventRecord(stop);

cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
float milliseconds = 0;

cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop);
```

Use chrono like this: ([std::chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
int main()
{
  auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  inferenceEngine(); // Do the inference
  auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

  std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end-start;
  std::time_t end_time = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end);

  std::cout << "finished computation at " << std::ctime(&end_time)
            << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n";
}
```